# how can i integrate virtual app in android application

Tags: java, android, virtual

I need to integrate [VirtualApp](https://github.com/asLody/VirtualApp) in the android application but the problem is that is has not been updated since 6 yrs except the docs, which are for commercial version. I tried to integrate it in my app following the [guide](https://github.com/asLody/VirtualApp/blob/master/doc/VADev_eng.md) but it is raising errors. Can anyone help me integrate it or suggest my any alternative solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent open code is available at https://github.com/FBlackBox/BlackBox. VirtulApp authors apparently bullied the project to close. The source code is still accessible on github as of posting of this comment, though.

Comment: Thanks for this but the code is not available in this repo. The author removed the code, only readme is available in which this issue has been listed. Do you have a cloned version?

Comment: Archived release tag still seems to work - https://github.com/FBlackBox/BlackBox/archive/refs/tags/2.1.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same open source project, VirtualAPP has stopped being open source and stopped updating, and the commercial version of it is expensive, up to 300,000 RMB a year license and 200,000 RMB/year technical support fees.

Comment: If I really can't find a similar open source project, I plan to use SpaceCore, which is much cheaper than VirtualApp. But I'm still trying to find open source projects, after all I don't have much money.